# XOR(a,b) for integers

Tags: python

> Give the Python function XOR(a,b) that returns the XOR(a,b) where a and b are integers. Submit a complete Python program that uses XOR in file xor.py

This is confusing to me, am I being asked to find integers for a and b
or is it saying a and b begin as integers? I'm generally very confused by
python so this probably seems like a simple question but I do not know where
to even begin with writing the code.

I know the outline of the code should be

```
def XOR(a,b):
    # Your code here

nbr1 = 67
nbr2 = 73
print (XOR(nbr1, nbr2))
```

Comment: It's saying that `a` and `b` are already integers.

Comment: I've made an edit that makes your outline of code more clear. Let us know if that is not correct or as you intended.  Basically, I think they just want you to write the function `XOR(a,b)`... Hint: It's incredibly simple, and only one line.

Comment: no it is correct, i'm just not sure how to begin writing the code. is it asking me to put it into binary or to return more integers? Also unsure what nbr1 and nbr2 are supposed to represent, I think they represent a and b but not 100% sure

Comment: you must use ints with xor so that should answer your  question

Comment: I've played around with a few of these suggestions but it just leads to python saying 'a is not defined' .. what exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 7):

The `^` operator in Python is XOR, so you can just do:

```
def XOR(a,b):
    return a ^ b

nbr1 = 67
nbr2 = 73
print (XOR(nbr1, nbr2))
```

Comment: this is not what the question asks

Comment: What is the question asking then?

Answer (score 0):

The XOR is just a binary function like OR, AND, NOT etc. You just have to create a def called XOR which takes two arguments and returns one of them raised to the other. This is the code:

```
def XOR(num1,num2):
    return num1^num2

print(XOR(5,3))
#prints 6
```

Edit: Assuming you don't know what XOR does, it basically evaluates the normal OR function on two decimal digits (after converting them to binary) and then applying the NOT operator which basically flips the output of the OR operator. For example, 5 in binary is 101 and 3 is 011. If we apply the XOR operator we get 110. See how the last digit of the output is the inverse of OR(1,1) and so on with the other digits. Python just deals with all this but after converting stuff from hex to binary and then outputting that binary in hex.

Answer (score -6):

`a` and `b` are integers to begin with.  XOR is shorthand for "Exclusive Or" or "Exclusive Disjunctive."  Basically, this means `a` or `b`, but not `a` and `b` ( remember that OR can mean `a` or `b` or `a` and `b`).  It sounds like you are being to write a function that when given two values returns one of the values.  You might try this:

```
import random
XOR(a, b):
    list = [a , b ]
    return random.choice(list)
```

Comment: This is not a XOR function